# How to check username availability and uniqueness in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net

In the simplest way: how can I check username availability?

When I enter a new user in a textbox and click on check availability button, if it is available it should display in green color that the username is available. And there should not duplicate usernames. I mean two username should not be identical.

Comment: How do you store your usernames? Are they in the database? In asp.net membership?

Comment: Hi Mr. David Basarab, I store usernames in database.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using the ASP.NET membership, you can just do:

```
string userNameToCheck = txt_Username.Text;

MembershipUser existingUser = Membership.GetUser(userNameToCheck);
bool exists = existingUser != null;
```

If you're using a database structure different to ASP.NET membership, you just have to do a `like` query on your user table (replacing UserTable, UserName and 'Username' respectively):

```
SELECT *
FROM 
   UserTable 
WHERE 
   UserName Like 'Username'
```

If you retrieve any results back, then that username has already been used.

Comment: return Membership.GetUser(txt_Username.Text) != null;

Comment: I broke it down into 3 lines to give a better example.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are storing the usernames in the database, you can make an Ajax call to check the availability in the database. jQuery has an excellent Ajax library.

Answer (score 0):

suppose you have username and password fields in your application.. when you enter something in username and click on tab,we have to check whether the username available or not... now i explain here

[image]

In the above page i have 2 boxes... double clcik on username textbox.. it will go to

protected void txtUsername_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }

[txtUsername is the name of  my username textbox]

now in that txtUsername_Textchanged event we have to write the code for availability of user..

whatever we are giving in username,it will compare with username column in database..
so first we retrieve the username column values in data reader.. then if we have rows in data reader then that username has already taken,if not it is available..

```
     protected void txtUsername_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)

   {

       if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtUsername.Text))
    {
```

SqlConnection con = new                          SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ymk"].ConnectionString);

```
      con.Open();
```

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select Location from Data where Location=@Name", con);

```
      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", txtUsername.Text);

         SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

          if (dr.HasRows)
        {
            checkusername.Visible = true;

            lblStatus.Text = "UserName Already Taken";
        }
        else
        {
            checkusername.Visible = true;

            lblStatus.Text = "UserName Available";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        checkusername.Visible = false;
    }
}
```